# How can I adjust a video position embedded in a Shiny App?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I need to adjust the video I insert into my Shiny App. As you can see the video is overlaying the text. However, I would like the video to be in the part where it is green and the text to be below the video. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

I use the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 
                                 div(
                                   style = 
                                     "height: 80px; background-color: #02BE7F; width: 100%; position: absolute; right:0;",
                                   tags$iframe(width="560", height="315", src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T1-k7VYwsHg", 
                                               frameborder="0", allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
                                               picture-in-picture", allowfullscreen=NA)
                                 ),
                                      style="text-align:center"),
                        
                                   hr(),
                                   br(),
                                   div(
                                     style = "width: 70%; margin: auto;",
                                     h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"), 
                                        style="text-align:justify")),
                                   tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")
                                 )
                                 
               



server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the height of your video iframe is 315, set the height of your green div to 315px and also replace `position: absolute` by `position: relative`.